# Django: can't store variable in self.xxx in Generic View?

Tags: django

**views.py**

```
class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.foo = "hi"    

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.foo)
```

`GET` request works but `POST` request doesn't work.

It occurs errors,
`AttributeError: 'MyView' object has no attribute 'foo'`

Can't I save variable in `self.xxx` in `views.py`?

Comment: @Sayse of course, it doesn't work. It just example!

Answer (score 1):

`get` & `post` methods are working independently and Django creates a new `MyView` instance on every request, that means when you first run `GET` request an instance of `MyView` class gets created, `foo` is assigned a value and after request has completed - `MyView` gets destroyed. When you make `POST` request - a new instance of `MyView` gets created again and it does not have that `foo` attribute anymore.

To keep some value between requests you have to use Sessions:

```
class MyView(View):

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       request.session['foo'] = "hi"  

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       print(request.session.get('foo', "default value"))
```